# JSON with Swift 2, Array Structure

Tags: json, swift2, swifty-json

I'm Having trouble with JSON and Swift 2.
I'm getting this Array from the server

```
[{"KidName":"Jacob","KidId":1,"GardenID":0},
{"KidName":"Sarah","KidId":2,"GardenID":0},
{"KidName":"Odel","KidId":3,"GardenID":0}]
```

I'm familiar with JSON and I know it's not the recommended way to get a JSON, since it's supposed to be something like

```
{"someArray":[{"KidName":"Jacob","KidId":1,"gardenID":0}, .....
```

So my first question is it possible to run over the first JSON I've post and get the KidName number without editing the JSON and Add to it a JSON OBJECT to hold the array ?

my second question is really with Swift 2, how can I get the KidName (after I've edited the JSON to have an holder for the array)?

this is my code... (please read the Notes I've added)
BTW, I'm familiar with SwiftyJSON as well...

```
// Method I've build to get the JSON from Server, the Data is the JSON
       sendGetRequest { (response, data ) -> Void in

        // need to convert data to String So I can add it an holder 
          if let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)            as? String {

                  /**
                 after editing the str, i'm Having a valid JSON, let's call it fixedJSON
                  */
                 let fixedJSON = "{\"kidsArray\":\(dropLast)}"

                  // Now I'm converting it to data back again
                    let jsonTodata = fixedJSON.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!

             // After Having the data, I need to convert it to JSON Format
                do{
                               let dataToJson = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonTodata, options: []) as!  [String:AnyObject]
                //Here I'm getting the KidID
                 if let kidID = jsonSe["kidsArray"]![0]["KidId"]!!.integerValue {
                    print("kidID in first index is: \(kidID)\n")
                }

                //NOW trying to get the KidName which not working
                  if let kidname = jsonSe["kidsArray"]![0]["KidName"]!!.stringValue {
                    print("KidName is \(kidname)\n")
                }

              }
```

So as you can see, I'm not able to get the KidName.
Any Help Would be Appreciate.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with receiving a plain array from the server. It's still valid JSON. The issue with your initial JSON is that none of the `KidName` attributes have closing quotes around them.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I've misType it wrong here. I'm surprise it's Valid JSON, Didn't know that. So How Can get the KidName out of the JSON... Since now I don't have to convert it to String->data->JSON...

Comment: I haven't worked with Swift, so I'm not 100% sure. I would check out http://www.raywenderlich.com/82706/working-with-json-in-swift-tutorial though and see if it leads you in the right direction (the article starts with a JSON array as well).

Comment: Ray is The Man ! I've read this article, but he got an Holder for the array, the problem I don't have an Holder for my array, as you said, it's plain array. when I'm editing the The JSON and add to it an holder it's work partially. I do get he KidID but not the KidName.

Comment: I don't see a holder for the array. He passes the array straight into SwiftyJSON (using the named `data` parameter): `JSON(data: data)`

Comment: True, I've Did that as well, let json = JSON(data: data) ... and when I print it it's a valid JSON, the question is how to get KidName out of it ? You do not have where to point to. let name = json["KidName"].stringValue won't work.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. What you've parsed is an array. You have to grab whichever object out of the array you want before trying to read the property: `json[0]["KidName"].stringValue`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function to get the 'someArray' array and then use this getStringFromJSON function to get the 'KidName' value.

```
func getArrayFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> NSArray {

    if let info = data[key] as? NSArray {
        return info
    }

    else {
        return []

    }

}

 let someArray = self.getArrayFromJSON(YourJSONArray as! NSDictionary, key: "someArray")


func getStringFromJSON(data: NSDictionary, key: String) -> String {

    if let info = data[key] as? String {
        return info
    }

    return ""
}

 let KidName = self.getStringFromJSON(someArray as! NSDictionary, key: "KidName")
```

Hope this might be useful to you.